Best way to update session value stored in redis without having access to HttpRequest or SecurityContextHolder
I have app which uses redis to store session, including Authentication object, using spring-boot.
Is there some proper way how to update this value without the user needing to logout( and thus deleting the redis stored session ) and login in again?
So far i am trying:
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class RedisService {

    private static final String PRINCIPAL_INDEX = "spring:session:index:" + FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME;
    private static final String ID = "spring:session:sessions:";

    @Autowired
    private RedisIndexedSessionRepository sessionRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    public void updateUserValue(String email) {
        // Retrieve the session using the email (principal)
        Map<String, ? extends Session> sessions = sessionRepository.findByPrincipalName(email);

        if (!sessions.isEmpty()) {
            // Loop through all sessions (if multiple exist)
            for (Session session : sessions.values()) {
                // Get the SecurityContext from the session

                SecurityContext securityContext = session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
                // Get the Redis key for the session data
                String sessionRedisKey = "spring:session:sessions:" + session.getId();
                if (securityContext != null) {
                    Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();

                    ClientPrincipal principal = (ClientPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
                    // update user's authorities
                    principal.setAuthorities(new CustomAuthority());

                    // Update the session with the modified SecurityContext
                    session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", securityContext);
                    securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);

                    redisTemplate.opsForHash().put(sessionRedisKey, "sessionAttr:SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", securityContext);
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("No session found for principal: " + email);
        }
    }
}

ClientPrincipal is my own implementation of UserDetails
but this does not update the value in redis for some reason. No additional key was created in redis, which should indicate key serialization is not making problems. I am also using default, spring autoconfigured RedisIndexedSessionRepository and RedisTemplate so serialization of values should also be correct.
Also "lastAccessedTime" of the key in redis has changed, yet the value remains the same, even trying to use dummy values does not work.
What could cause the problems? Is somehow spring preventing direct updates ?
As a bypass for directly manipulating redis value, i was thinking about creating filter that would check for updates and then update the session itself ( since the changes in session should reflected in redis if we have HttpSession), but that sounds like some last resort.
Thanks for help
